# Installing fastANI trough conda

Tags: conda

I've tried to install the fastANI tool trough conda with the following commands

```
conda install -c bioconda fastani
conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 fastani
```

However it doesn't like it...

(base) user@user:~$  conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 fastani
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

```
Specifications:

  - fastani -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - fastani -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing into a new environment:

```bash
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge -c bioconda fastani
## to use, activate environment
conda activate foo
```

Note that [Bioconda packages assume the **conda-forge** channel has highest priority](http://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels), hence why `-c conda-forge -c bioconda` (order matters). Also, don't use the alternative labels that Anaconda Cloud suggests (e.g., `bioconda/label/cf201901`). Those are for advanced usage; it would be better that Anaconda Cloud didn't suggest them at all, but that's the UX for now.